# Post migrated to meta can be double up voted

Tags: feature-request, bug, voting, migration, meta

Recently we moved a post to meta that was on main. While on main it garnered several upvotes, including one from me. When it appeared the UV button didn't have the pressed look... so I pressed it and the count went up. Other users confirmed the behavior. This **allows users to double upvote a post**